# How to extract strings on Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a newbie to python and I would like to take strings per each element in a Python list.

So the elements in my list look like

```
"name", "id": 1, "localized_name", ...
```

And I would like to have only "name", and delete all the strings, "id": 1, "localized_name", ...

```
for i in range(113):
    dota2_hero[i].rstrip('''"id": ''')
```

Comment: `["name", "id": 1, "localized_name"]` is not a valid Python list. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: For example the first element in my list is '''"antimage", "id": 1, "localized_name"''', I have 10k those string elements in my list. I want to remove all the strings after "name" and leave only name part

Comment: So does it look like this: `['''"name", "id": 1, "localized_name"''', ... ]`?

Comment: Yes, and they are all strings. I took this from json file

Comment: If `l` is the list containing your data you can do as follow: `names = [x.split(",")[0] for x in l]`

Answer (score 0):

If `l` is the list containing your data you can do as follow:

`names = [x.split(",")[0] for x in l]`